# How to create knockout data bindings at runtime w/o data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, javascript-framework

Is it possible to create knockout bindings from javascript alone, i.e. without writing custom html attributes?

I'm very much stuck with our existing markup and can't add `data-bind` etc. that knockout.js relies on (html is generated programmatically and there is no access to the rendering pipeline, please assume I've exhausted my options in trying :)

One idea that I'm tentatively pursuing is adding `data-bind` attributes at runtime prior to calling `ko.applyBindings`. Is there a preferred approach? I'll also accept an alternative, sufficiently documented/popular/stable framework if it also implements bindings similar to knockout.js `if`/`visible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout 3.0 (which just around the corner and is in release candidate now) opens up a [lot more ways to interact with the binding process](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.0.0beta), such as the ability to preprocess nodes and dynamically generate bindings. Take a look at [Knockout.Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) to see some examples of what is possible. Between that and the things already mentioned like the [unobtrusive](https://github.com/tobio/knockout.unobtrusivebindingprovider) and [class](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider) binding providers, you should have no trouble working with whatever markup you're stuck with.

It may also be worth pointing out knockout has an applyBindingsToNode function which takes in a JSON object of the bindings if you want full control, though that does not apply bindings to descendant elements.

Comment: Punches look useful. Still, I'm coming to believe that what I'm after is *really* a knockout antipattern - it's implied that I effectively have no control over the "VM" part of the MVVM pattern :(

Comment: To be a little more specific, you have no control over the View, which is the V part of MVVM. I think that this approach is most definitely a route that is less than ideal - and I think you've realized as well. But if there's really no way you can modify the HTML, then you have no choice but to do something a little off the beaten path.

Answer (score 2):

Knockout allow us to create custom binding provider, I find out there is several libs  that help you to do it

You can find them here:

One that don't use DOM at all:

> https://github.com/tobio/knockout.unobtrusivebindingprovider

One that use another approach :

> https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-classBindingProvider

At last resort if none of them suit your needs, you can with jQuery modify the DOM then call the binding on it...

Comment: *unobtrusivebindingprovider* looks useful, although with very limited activity (FTFY: it *does* use DOM, but it doesn't use markup for data binding, which is exactly what I'm after)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the "Unobtrusive event handling" section in the Knockout documentation under "Further techniques".

Comment: I don't see how I'd use [that](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) - it seems to provide an unobtrusive way to delegate only interactivity handlers (`click` etc.) as opposed to a full set of knockout.js bindings including `data-bind="value:whatever"` and conditionals. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not an answer. This is directions to where an answer might be as long as Knockout doesn't change the content of their pages.